# How to read a number from an NSMutableArray inside a subclass objective C

Tags: nsmutablearray

I have a calculation inside a subclass to be done. however I'm totally stuck because I cant read the property self.productNumber inside my method inside the subclass. I need to create the method CalculatePayment. How can I solve this problem?

### Products.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Product : NSObject

//Property
@property int ProductID;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString* productName;
@property float productPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString* productMadeInCountry;

//Contructor
-(id) initWithProductID:(int)productID productName:(NSString*)productName productPrice:(float)productPrice productMadeInCountry:(NSString*)productMadeInCountry;
-(id) initWithProductName:(NSString*)productName;

@end
```

---

```
Products.m

    #import "Product.h"

    @implementation Product

    - (id) initWithProductID:(int)productID productName:(NSString*)productName productPrice:(float)productPrice productMadeInCountry:(NSString*)productMadeInCountry
    {
        self = [super init];
        if(self)
        {
            self.ProductID = productID;
            self.productName = productName;
            self.productPrice = productPrice;
            self.productMadeInCountry = productMadeInCountry;
        }
        return self;
    }

    -(id) initWithProductName:(NSString*)productName
    {
        self = [super init];
        if(self)
        {
            self.productName = productName;
        }
        return self;
    }
    @end
```

---

```
 Shopping_Cart.h

        #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Product.h"

@interface Shopping_Cart : NSObject
//property
@property NSMutableArray<Product*>* items;
//Constructor

-(id)initWithItems:(NSMutableArray<Product*>*)items productPrice:(float)productPrice;

//Methods(APIs)
-(void)addItem:(Product*) product;
-(float)calculatePurchase:(Product*) productPrice;
-(void)printProductName:(Product*)productName;


@end
```

---

```
#import "Shopping_Cart.h"


@implementation Shopping_Cart

-(id)initWithItems:(NSMutableArray<Product*>*)items productPrice:(float)productPrice
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.items = items;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)addItem:(Product*) product
{
    NSLog(@"The item is added to your shopping cart!");
    [self.items addObject:product];
}

-(float)calculatePurchase:(Product*) product
{

    float totalPrice = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < self.items.count; i++)
    {
        totalPrice = totalPrice + self.items[i];
    }


    return totalPrice;

}
-(void)printProductName:(Product*)productName
{
    NSLog(@"\n===================\n");
    NSLog(@"Product Name: %@\n", self.productName);
    NSLog(@"\n===================\n");
}


@end
```

Comment: Where and how did you declare the property `productNumber`? What did you try to create the method `CalculatePayment`?

Comment: Actually, I put some thing I was trying. I'll update the coding.

Comment: code is already  Updated!

Comment: I still don't see `productNumber` or `CalculatePayment`.